# Looking for a faster way to update many Columns on SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Been new to SQL, would anyone know a faster way of doing the below updates?

Maybe using an Array or For each element.

```
update ItemDynamic
set price = SnapShotPrice
where SnapShotPrice <> Price

update ItemDynamic
Set PriceLevelA = SnapShotPriceA
where snapshotpriceA <> PricelevelA

update ItemDynamic
Set PriceLevelB = SnapshotpriceB
where snapshotpriceB <> PricelevelB

update ItemDynamic
Set PriceLevelC = SnapshotpriceC
where snapshotpriceC <> PricelevelC
```

Comment: They're called indexes.  SSMS comes with a query analyzer that can suggest indexes to add.  You should use it.

Comment: Update statements 3 and 4 appear to be the same. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in a single update statement. Something like this.

```
update ItemDynamic
SET price = CASE WHEN SnapShotPrice <> Price then SnapShotPrice ELSE price end
    , PriceLevelA = CASE WHEN snapshotpriceA <> PricelevelA then SnapShotPriceA ELSE PriceLevelA end
    , PriceLevelB = CASE WHEN snapshotpriceB <> PricelevelB THEN SnapshotpriceB ELSE PriceLevelB end
```

Not really sure what the point of your fourth update statement is because it is identical to the third one.

Comment: If none of the columns involved are nullable, this can be further simplified to `SET Price = SnapshotPrice` etc. It's worth pointing out that in this form, the statement will update every row unconditionally (even if just idempotently), while the original statements do not. This may or may not be faster, depending on indexes and data distribution.

Comment: I considered adding the predicates to limit the rows being updated but that would very likely be slower as there would be multiple not equals predicates. Given the incredibly vague question I was merely trying to point out that it could be done in a single statement instead of 3 (or 4).

Comment: Understood, but as the original specifically asked for "faster" (which for all we know may just be "less code"), I felt obliged to point out that the mileage of this solution can vary. In particular, people are often surprised that an update of the form `SET Column = Column` is *not* a no-op that writes no data.